# Sencha Touch, Phonegap Facebook Integration

Tags: facebook, cordova, sencha-touch, facebook-javascript-sdk

for Sencha Touch, I have used Facebook JS SDK to allow user to login. It runs pretty well in the browser.

But after building it into PhoneGap project, the Facebook JS SDK won't work in the native iOS app, because running the JS SDK needs a browser.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the InAppBrowser  plugin: https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/658 or better yet use the Facebook Connect plugin: https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/257

The Facebook Connect plugin will use the native Facebook application on the users device (if they have it) whilst still using the JavaScript SDK. If the user does not have Facebook installed it will fall back to using the browser.

Comment: Hi JoshMorony, thanks for answering! I have found the Facebook Connect plugin but there is not much documentation about how to use it, can you briefly explain that? Thanks!

Comment: I've written a blog post about posting to a Facebook wall here using the plugin: http://www.joshmorony.com/posting-to-a-facebook-wall-with-phonegap-the-javascript-sdk/ but don't actually cover the setup. Essentially though, there is no difference. You can just use the JavaScript SDK as normal, include the plugin and it should just work. Just remember to declare your App Name / App Id in the config.xml file (I think that is in the documentation).